# startActivityForResult alternative with bundle option

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I previously used the below code to start an activity with bundle options (some animation options) for result.

```
public void openActivityForResultOld(Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(this,
        android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1, bundle);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // got result...
}
```

Due to depreciation of `startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle)`, I currently using the code below:

```
public void openActivityForResult(Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(this,
        android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle();

    ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> mStartForResult = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                // got result...
            }
        });
        
    // Here I am able pass the intent, not with the bundle
    // How to pass bundle here?
    
    mStartForResult.launch(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
}
```

But can't pass the bundle with animation options.

How can I implement this? Please help.

Comment: there is a version of `ActivityResultLauncher.launch` with `ActivityOptionsCompat` ... also YOU SHOULD CALL `registerForActivityResult` outside the method!!! it have to be called every time new activity is created in other case it will not work after activity recreation

Comment: Oops! I didn't notice it. Thanks. If you post as a answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0):

just add option in launch argument

```
val option = ActivityOptions...
mStartForResult.launch(yourInput, option)
```